# std::map access operator deprecated? no operator [] matches these operands

Tags: c++, c++11

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/, I can use either `m[k]` or `m.at(k)` to access the value of a key `k` in a map `m`. However, when I try to do

```
derivMap[fx]
```

in my code, where derivMap is an element of type `std::map<std::string,std::string>` Visual Studio 2013 gives me the warning

> no operator [] matches these operands

However, when I change my code to

```
derivMap.at(fx)
```

I get no error. Do you have any insight into this issue?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[`map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) is not deprecated.

I will guess that you are attempting to call the operator in a context where `derivMap` is `const`. `map::operator[]` does not have a `const` overload, because it can modify the map by inserting an element when one matching the key isn't present. `map::at()` on the other hand, does have a `const` overload because it is designed to throw when an element is not found.

```
void foo(std::map<int, int>& m)
{
  int n = m[42]; // OK
}

void bar(const std::map<int, int>& m)
{
  int n = m[42]; // ERROR
}
```

Comment: I prefer `.find` to `.at`.  I never use `.at`.

Comment: @MooingDuck I guess it depends on whether the absence of an element is an error or not (and whether you have C++11.)

Comment: In my case the problem was the const environment as correctly suggested by @juanchopanza
It can also depend on the method signature e.g.
`void SomeClass::foo() const{
    int n = this->m[42]
}`
Where m is a field of the class 'SomeClass'.
In this case the **const** is causing this behaviour.