# Accessing an entry in std::map causes 'no operator "[]" matches these operands'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn c++, so apologies if this is a silly question. I am trying to replicate what I can do in C# when accessing field names of a database query

so

myRow["field"]

would return the value of the field in the current row

Now here is the code I have to create a std:map which models the table and Rows.

```
void DATAENGINE_API DataEngine::ExecuteQuery(char * sqlStatement)
{
    SQLRETURN retCode;
    SQLHANDLE hEnv;
    SQLHANDLE hConn;
    SQLHANDLE hStmt;

    SQLCHAR* dsnName;
    SQLCHAR* uid;
    SQLCHAR* pwd;

    SQLCHAR* query;

    SQLLEN numRows;
    SQLSMALLINT numCols;

    retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
    CHECK(retCode, "allocate environment handle");

    retCode = SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    CHECK(retCode, "setting the environment attribute setting to ODBC version 3");
    CHECK(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hConn), "allocate handle");

    dsnName = (SQLCHAR*)dsn;
    uid = (SQLCHAR*)userId;
    pwd = (SQLCHAR*)password;

    retCode = SQLConnectA(hConn, dsnName, SQL_NTS, uid, SQL_NTS, pwd, SQL_NTS);

    if (!CHECK(retCode, "SqlConnectA", false)) {
        Status(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hConn, __LINE__);
    }

    CHECK(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hConn, &hStmt), "allocate handle for statement");
    query = (SQLCHAR*)sqlStatement;

    CHECK(SQLExecDirectA(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS), "execute query");

    retCode = SQLFetch(hStmt);

    CHECK(retCode, "first sqlFetch");

    retCode = SQLRowCount(hStmt, &numRows);
    retCode = SQLNumResultCols(hStmt, &numCols);

    // traverse the results to create a table view.
    std::map<int, Row> t;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        std::map<std::string, std::string> r;

        for (int j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {

            SQLCHAR colName[256];
            char buf[256];

            SQLSMALLINT colNameLen, dataType, numDecimalDigits, allowsNullValues;
            SQLUINTEGER columnSize;
            SQLINTEGER numBytes;
            std::string fieldName;

            retCode = SQLDescribeColA(hStmt, j, colName, 255, &colNameLen, &dataType, &columnSize, &numDecimalDigits, &allowsNullValues);
            fieldName = (char*)colName;

            retCode = SQLGetData(

                hStmt,
                j,           // COLUMN NUMBER of the data to get
                SQL_C_CHAR,  // the data type that you expect to receive
                buf,         // the place to put the data that you expect to receive
                255,         // the size in bytes of buf (-1 for null terminator)
                &numBytes    // size in bytes of data returned

                );

            // r.insert(std::make_pair(fieldName, buf))
            r.insert(std::make_pair(fieldName, buf));
        }

        t[i] = r;
    }

}
```

However when I try and use the following code

r["myfield"]

VS is throwing  'no operator "[]" matches these operands' error.

Looking at this link [std::map access operator deprecated? no operator [] matches these operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833179/stdmap-access-operator-deprecated-no-operator-matches-these-operands)

I have even tried

r.insert(std::make_pair(fieldName, buf));

based on a suggestion here; [How to create a std::map of constant values which is still accessible by the [] operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708618/how-to-create-a-stdmap-of-constant-values-which-is-still-accessible-by-the)

and I still get the same error.

I would expect this to work - so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `map` requires type arguments but you don't show them in your example code. (Your example code doesn't make sense)

Comment: What's `r['myfield']`? Why are you using single quotes??? Where exactly in the code you posted are you getting the error?

Comment: you say 'throwing' but what you give looks like a compile time error. Is it a compile error?

Comment: might be missing some header include? maybe `<map>`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your use of `std::make_pair` is the problem.  You need to create an `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` explicitly.  The [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) function template creates a pair based on the types of its inputs.

```
        char buf[256];
        //  [...]

        r.insert(std::make_pair(fieldName, buf));
        // std::make_pair returns std::pair<std::string, char*>
```

Normally, in C++, a `char*` will implicitly convert to `std::string`.  It looks like your compiler or your standard library is not picking up the conversion between the pair containing the type.

Try this instead:

```
        r.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(fieldName, buf));
```

If you prefer, you can shorten this with a typedef:

```
        typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> string_pair;

        r.insert(string_pair(fieldName, buf));
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your problem description, which as I’m writing this says that

> **”** when I try and use the following code
>
> ```
> r["myfield"]
> ```
>
> VS is throwing 'no operator "[]" matches these operands' error.

Well the following works:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

auto main() -> int
{
    std::map< std::string, std::string > r;

    r["blah"] = "foo";
}
```

So there your interpretation of things is incorrect. Most likely the code you have presented is **not the real code**. I would surmise that you are correctly quoting the error message.

Answer (score -1):

The operator[] takes the same type as the key. Your key is a string, but you are passing a constant character pointer.

This is similar to 01d55's answer about your incorrect pair types. Using his suggestion of creating string using the character pointer should fix both problems.

Comment: re "but you are passing a constant character pointer.", that is not a problem.

Comment: Unless there is a conversion operator defined for char* to std::string, it is a problem. `r` is of type `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, which means the `[]` operator expects a `std::string`.

Comment: why not **check things** before asserting beliefs here.

Comment: In that case, would you kindly elaborate?

Comment: I tried testing if it works and it froze my computer, so I officially don't know anymore.

Comment: `std::string` has an implicitly invokable converting constructor. the freeze you experienced is unrelated. unless you passed a nullpointer.